# Creating repeated sequential number based on parameter?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sapb1

i'm essentially trying to create a unique barcode for an invoice in SAP Business one, based on a parameter from the invoice screen and the invoice number.

For the example, the fixed data I will have is "Invoice Number" with a parameter called "Number Of Items"

If the parameter is 10, i want the SQL query to return...

```
123456 001 010
123456 002 010
123456 003 010
123456 004 010
123456 005 010
```

etc. This would essentially create me 10 unique numbers which I can then use for a series of barcodes for this invoice?
It doesn't need to be inserted into a table, it just needs to be able to calculate that middle dynamic value.

The values i will be querying on are

OINV.InvoiceNumber, OINV.NumberOfParcels FROM OINV

Many Thanks

Andy

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: This is for SAP Business one, and i'm using MsSQL studio 17

Comment: *"MsSQL studio 17"? That's isn't an RDBMS. *Perhaps* you means SQL Server management Studio, which is an IDE for SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a numbers table you can simply do this:

```
DECLARE @SomeNumber INT = 123456,
        @N          INT = 10;

SELECT
  SomeNumber = @SomeNumber,
  Col1       = STUFF('000',3+1-LEN(t.N),LEN(t.N),t.N),
  Col2       = STUFF('000',3+1-LEN(@N),LEN(@N),@N)
FROM  Numbers AS t
WHERE t.N <= @N;
```

If you don't you could use [fnTally](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/create-a-tally-function-fntally). The code would look like this:

```
SELECT 
  SomeNumber = @SomeNumber,
  Col1       = STUFF('000',3+1-LEN(t.N),LEN(t.N),t.N),
  Col2       = STUFF('000',3+1-LEN(@N),LEN(@N),@N)
FROM   dbo.fnTally(1,@N) AS t;
```

Both Queries Return:

```
SomeNumber  Col1    Col2    
----------- ------- ------- 
123456      001     010     
123456      002     010     
123456      003     010     
123456      004     010     
123456      005     010     
123456      006     010     
123456      007     010     
123456      008     010     
123456      009     010     
123456      010     010
```